# Efficiently creating columns from GroupBy Operations

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

**Given** is a DataFrame like this:

```
   kind       seen
0  tiger 2019-01-01
1  tiger 2019-01-02
2   bird 2019-01-03
3  whale 2019-01-04
4   bird 2019-01-05
5  tiger 2019-01-06
6   bird 2019-01-07
```

The **Goal** is to group the dataframe by the kind of animal and having the two latest dates as column values :

```
      last_seen   second_last_seen
bird  2019-01-07  2019-01-05
tiger 2019-01-06  2019-01-02
whale 2019-01-04         NaT
```

---

My current Solution is vastly inefficient, it goes like this:

**1. Creating the Dataframe**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"kind": ["tiger", "tiger", "bird", "whale", "bird", "tiger", "bird"], 
        "seen": pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods = 7)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Dataframe:

```
   kind       seen
0  tiger 2019-01-01
1  tiger 2019-01-02
2   bird 2019-01-03
3  whale 2019-01-04
4   bird 2019-01-05
5  tiger 2019-01-06
6   bird 2019-01-07
```

**2. Calculating the latest dates with groupby**

```
df = df.groupby('kind')['seen'].nlargest(2)
```

Dataframe:

```
kind    
bird   6   2019-01-07
       4   2019-01-05
tiger  5   2019-01-06
       1   2019-01-02
whale  3   2019-01-04
```

Here lies the problem, the second level of the `MultiIndex` keeps the original indices of the dates as value.

Meaning, if I now `df.unstack()` the Dataframe it looks like this:

```
               1          3          4          5          6
kind                                                        
bird         NaT        NaT 2019-01-05        NaT 2019-01-07
tiger 2019-01-02        NaT        NaT 2019-01-06        NaT
whale        NaT 2019-01-04        NaT        NaT        NaT
```

the goal is to look like this:

```
      last_seen   second_last_seen
bird  2019-01-07  2019-01-05
tiger 2019-01-06  2019-01-02
whale 2019-01-04         NaT
```

**3. Transform the Dataframe in a really ugly way**

I change the second level of the MultiIndex to values that allow `df.unstack()` to unstack the Dataframe just like the goal Dataframe

```
# Keeping track of the latest animal seen
predecessor_id = None
counter = 1
result = list()

for row in df.index:
    if predecessor_id != row[0]:
        counter = 1
    else:
        counter += 1
    result.append((row[0], counter))
    predecessor_id = row[0]

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(result)
```

Dataframe:

```
bird   1   2019-01-07
       2   2019-01-05
tiger  1   2019-01-06
       2   2019-01-02
whale  1   2019-01-04
```

`df.unstack` and renaming the columns then gives us goal Dataframe:

```
      last_seen   second_last_seen
bird  2019-01-07  2019-01-05
tiger 2019-01-06  2019-01-02
whale 2019-01-04         NaT
```

---

Needless to say, this solution is overkill and unpythonic to the core.

Thank you for your time and happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

```
s = df.groupby('kind')['seen'].tail(2)
new_df = df.loc[df['seen'].isin(s)].groupby('kind').agg(['last','first'])
```

then we just need to remove values where first and last are the same, indicating there was only one value in the original data frame.

```
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.droplevel()
new_df.loc[a['first'] == new_df['last'],'last'] = pd.NaT
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.map(lambda x : x + '_seen')

       last_seen first_seen
kind                       
bird  2019-01-07 2019-01-05
tiger 2019-01-06 2019-01-02
whale        NaT 2019-01-04
```

Comment: Thank you! it displays wrong value for the 'whale' row though.

Comment: @aitak edited for you, but anky's is better as mine is 5 lines of code and his is 3 :)

Answer (score 1):

here is a way :

```
grp=df.groupby('kind')['seen'].nlargest(2).droplevel(1).to_frame()
grp=grp.set_index(grp.groupby(grp.index).cumcount(),append=True).unstack()

grp.columns=['last_seen','second_last_seen']
print(grp)
```

---

```
       last_seen second_last_seen
kind                             
bird  2019-01-07       2019-01-05
tiger 2019-01-06       2019-01-02
whale 2019-01-04              NaT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
g = df.sort_values('seen').groupby('kind')['seen']
df2 = g.nth(-1).rename('last_seen').to_frame()
df2['second_last_seen'] = g.nth(-2)
```

The result will be:

```
       last_seen second_last_seen
kind                             
bird  2019-01-07       2019-01-05
tiger 2019-01-06       2019-01-02
whale 2019-01-04              NaT
```

And you can use this solutions if you want more columns:

```
g = df.sort_values('seen').groupby('kind')['seen']
df2 = g.nth(-1).rename('last_seen').to_frame()
for k in range(2,4):
    df2[str(k)+'_last_seen'] = g.nth(-k)
```

Which results in:

```
       last_seen 2_last_seen 3_last_seen
kind                                    
bird  2019-01-07  2019-01-05  2019-01-03
tiger 2019-01-06  2019-01-02  2019-01-01
whale 2019-01-04         NaT         NaT
```

UPD: added sort by 'seen' column because it is necessary in general case. Thanks @aitak

Comment: Your resolution is only right when the dates are sorted correctly (which is the case in my given example to be fair), since `.nth()` takes the nth row of the group with no concern if the group is sorted or not

Comment: @aitak Of course, you are right. In general case you need to sort df by 'seen' column. That was an example of idea, but I'll add 'sort' into answer to make it more accurate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution (if "seen" is of Timestamp dtype):

```
s=df.groupby("kind")["seen"].agg(lambda t: t.nlargest(2).to_list())                                                  

s                                                                                                                    

kind
bird     [2019-01-07 00:00:00, 2019-01-05 00:00:00]
tiger    [2019-01-06 00:00:00, 2019-01-02 00:00:00]
whale                         [2019-01-04 00:00:00]
Name: seen, dtype: object

pd.DataFrame( s.to_list(),index=s.index).rename(columns={0:"last_seen",1:"second_last_seen"})                        

       last_seen second_last_seen
kind                             
bird  2019-01-07       2019-01-05
tiger 2019-01-06       2019-01-02
whale 2019-01-04              NaT
```